# How did the prepositions up and down both come to be associated with writing?

Tags: etymology

Per this question ["Writing things down" vs. "writing things up"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58522/writing-things-down-vs-writing-things-up), it is clear that things can be written "up" (typically in respect to longer entries that are being thoroughly considered) or "down" (typically in respect to quick notes.)

My question is more etymological - the prepositions used would seem to be directional.  I would have thought "about" or even "on" would be more logical.  And, while one can write "about" a topic or "on" a subject, the prevelance of Up and Down cannot be denied.

So, how is it, etymologically speaking, that things came to be written up or down?  Did these happen more or less simultaneously,  or is it just a happy circumstance?  And why up and down?

Comment: OED dates *write up* to 1425, and attributes *write down* to Shakespeare. It's possible he was expanding the language again by using an unusual preposition to nuance an existing expression.

Comment: @AndrewLeach really? That sounds interesting. Could you post that entry for the benefit of those of us unfortunate enough not to have access to the OED?

Comment: **Write down**: 1594   Shakespeare *Titus Andronicus* ii. iv. 3   Write downe thy minde bewray thy meaning so. **Write up**: a1530 (1425) Andrew of Wyntoun *Oryg. Cron. Scotl.* (Royal) ix. l. 1177,   I wyll noucht wryt wp all, That I hawe sene in my tyme fall.

Comment: **Write out**: 1548. **Write off** (=cancel debt) 1682. **Write in** (=insert) 1382; (=send a message) 1928. **Write over** 1597, Shakespeare again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most English prepositions and phrasal verb particles have **some** intrinsic physical meaning, usually from the perspective of a human body. For instance,

- We refer to something or someone being located
  [***at** a point, **on** a surface,* or ***in** a container*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/71574/15299)
- We refer to something (the trajector) moving
  [***from** one location or actor* (the source)

  ***to** another location or patient* (the goal)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/15299).

All of these have many other, often idiomatic, metaphoric, and non-physical meanings, too.
And there's loads more prepositions and phrasal verb particles left.
But I'm not going to deal with them here; life is short.

This is only about ***up*** and ***down***.

---

*Up* and *down* are directions, but they're directions from the viewpoint of a human. Humans have evolved and adapted to a 1-G environment; we have built-in senses to detect up and down; it's **important** to humans.

For example, imagine a standing human:

- ***Up*** means the direction from the feet to the head, and continuing beyond.
  ***Down*** is the opposite direction.

It is crucial to our species that we can move freely in the first two dimensions -- on a surface -- but we **can't** move freely in the third, *up/down*, dimension. Birds and fish have true three-dimensional motion; humans have, at best, 2½-dimensional motion.

But we can **look** *up*, even if we can't always **go** *up*; and we can tell when something's there. Whether it is or not. That's the source for most of the [metaphoric senses of *up* and *down*](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Metaphors.pdf),
which are frequent visitors to [phrasal verbs](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/phrasals.html).

These senses often converge on the same situation, as in

1. *He drank it down ~ He drank it up*
2. *The house burned down ~ The house burned up*
3. *I'll write that down ~ I'll write that up*

In each of these, the meaning is not **quite** the same.

The *down* cases refer to **Physical** *down* --

- the beer is now down in the stomach;
- the house was high, now there's only ground left;
- the writing has been physically put down on the paper
  (this is also coherent with `DOWN` is `CONCRETE`;
  writing is very concrete, compared to talk)

But the *up* cases refer to **Completive** *up*. That's the *up* that means 'to completion; all the way'
You get it in phrasal verbs like
*tie (it) up, pack (it) up, finish (it) up, screw (it) up*, which mean
to do `whatever the verb phrase is` as much, as thoroughly, and as completely as possible.

In that context, it's easy to see that beer that is drunk totally has moved downwards,
and that a house that is completely burned is burned to the ground,
and that something that has been written completely is written down on some medium.

There are situations where they fit in different configurations, and -- depending on context and idiom -- you can sometimes see the cracks where they don't quite fit.

> As one example, to *write something up* means to produce a finished version, while to *write something down* merely means to make a note.
>
> For another, only constructions that are rooted on the ground -- like houses -- can *burn down* or *burn to the ground*; if an airliner was completely destroyed by a fire while on the ground you could say that it *burned up*, but not that it *burned down* or *burned to the ground*.
>
> For still another, *drink up* is coherent with the physical upward movement of the drink container to the lips, while *drink down* is coherent with the reduced vertical level of the liquid in the container after drinking.

As to when this happened, there are dates in dictionaries; they represent first appearance in surviving text, which may or may not represent actual speech. But the meanings are primal enough to occur to anybody, and to be easily passed along to the next generation where they hadn't already been figured out. Like a lot of things, they keep getting rediscovered and reinforced.

So it isn't that *up* and *down* are associated with writing as such, it's just that they form pretty typical phrasal verbs with *write*, just like they do with thousands of other verbs.

Comment: What about the phrase; "I would like to *take up* dancing?" That has a different meaning from thoroughly completing a task, and there's nothing directional that could indicate to a non-native speaker its real meaning. Nevertheless, I shall remember your clear explanation and examples (really appreciate "the house burned up/down") next time a student asks me why we have the phrasal expression "write down". I had always said because we put our pens *down* on paper while conveniently ignoring the "write up" expression. Thank you.

Comment: The completive is only one of the several senses of _up_. The sense of _take up_ is a metaphorical physical one, not a completive one. The metaphor is that activities are objects (on a table, say) which are taken up, used, and put away like toys, so _taking up dancing_ means picking up that toy from the metaphoric table of one's activities. Another case of UP is ACTIVE.

Comment: BTW, @Mari-LouA, I hadn't meant this list to be exhaustive, just exemplary. As I said, life is short. But thank you, in turn. We try.

Comment: Yes, it was clear that you were focussing on the specific question but I had read the link and I couldn't see where "take up" fitted. I do now so, many thanks again.

Comment: Also BTW, "down on paper" is completely coherent, too. There are a lot of ways to get to the same place; that's what metaphors are **for**.